# PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR is not set correctly - wamp 64bit with php5.3.13

Tags: php, wamp, pear

I am using wamp 64bit with php5.5.12.

I followed all 10 steps from:

> http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/29976/install-pear-on-windows-7-64x-using-wamp/

There's actually no problem with the installation nor the path but when I tried to check if pear was working by typing `pear`, instead of displaying list of commands it displayed this:

> **PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR is not set correctly.
>   Please fix it using your environment variable or modify
>   the defaul value in pear.bat
>   The current value is:
>   C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\pear**

I have no idea where the **php5.3.13** come from since I am using **php5.5.12**.

I even checked the code of the pear.bat and the PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR is actually correct.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: in step 2 I see this line Put this file in the following directory: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.1.13 . Are you sure you used 5.5.12 there? also I would like to check the output of php -v

Comment: try the suggested error `PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR` set this to your environment variable, and use the path you have installed

Comment: @satya - yes I am sure that I put it in 5.5.12 since it's the only existing php version in the php directory.

Comment: @Ghost - I also tried that but it didn't work. I was hoping if someone also experienced this issue

Comment: Is it possible you have multiple versions of php on your machine?

Comment: @Rachael - Nope, I only have 1 php version on my wamp. That's why I was wondering how the pear installation got the 5.3.13

Comment: What version does it show when you open up the pear.bat file?

Comment: @Rachael - it's this one : IF "%PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR%"=="" SET "PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR=C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\pear"

Comment: Is it possible to directly set it to php5.5.12 in the bat file (ie take out the if?  I'm just wondering if it's seeing 5.3.13 when it does the if comparison.

Comment: @Rachael - I removed the if and it totally works, WOW! Thank you so much. It's kinda weird though because I put the environment variable correctly but it didn't see it in the pear.bat

Comment: Welcome to php...haha

Answer (score 3):

You have to change your environment variables.

Go to `Start > Control Panel > System > Environment` and modify the `PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR` variable.

Comment: Needed to set not the pear.php but just pear folder, in case some have same problem. And also restart cmd.